# PHP Function to get difference element from both arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Here's the situations:
I have 2 arrays, eg:

```
$a=array('a','b','c','d');
$b=array('1','b','c','e');
```

I want to produce 2 arrays with result:

```
$c=array('a','d');//only element appeared on $a
$d=array('1','e');//only element appeared on $b
```

Do you have a clever solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$c = array_diff($a, $b);
$d = array_diff($b, $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. It turn out a was giving the wrong array in my test.
simple array_diff solved the problem:
`$c = array_diff($a, $b);
$d = array_diff($b, $a);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the array_diff() function:

```
array_diff(array1,array2,array3...)
```

eg:

```
<?php
$a1=array(0=>"Cat",1=>"Dog",2=>"Horse");
$a2=array(3=>"Horse",4=>"Dog",5=>"Fish");
print_r(array_diff($a1,$a2));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Cat )
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array_diff.asp